# Is there a way to jump to start of output in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am running some unit tests by calling a script in Cygwin.  My issue is that I apparently broke something in my code, and now the unit test output is many hundreds of lines.  I need to jump to the start of the output in order to figure out what it going on.  Scrolling is taking forever, and it is entirely too easy to scroll right past the start of the output.

Is there a shortcut to jump to the start of the output? Google gave me nothing, so I'm hoping someone here knows.

Comment: presumably you're using 'less' as the pager? `0G` will take you to the end of the content, and `/foo` will jump down to the first instance of `foo` in the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the pager.

Comment: "more" or "less", the thing that gives you the "press any key for next page"

Comment: Can also clear the terminal before starting the next request.